# The tag helper 'option' must not have c# in the element's attribute declaration area

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-5

I have this problem and i can't figure out how to fix that

```
 <option value="10" @(Model.ItemsTo == 10 ? "selected" : "")>10</option>
 <option value="25" @(Model.ItemsTo == 25 ? "selected" : "")>25</option>
 <option value="50" @(Model.ItemsTo == 50 ? "selected" : "")>50</option>
```

I'm using bootstrap 5 and it is my MVC project.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro?view=aspnetcore-1.0#c-in-tag-helpers-attributedeclaration), believe that you are using ASP.NET Core MVC has restricted the code above which works fine in ASP.NET MVC:

> Tag Helpers do not allow C# in the element's attribute or tag declaration area.

You can use the tag helper to bind the value for the `<select>` element.

```
<select asp-for="itemsTo">
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="25">25</option>
    <option value="50">50</option>
</select>
```

Comment: It won't help beacuse i wan't to have static elements 10,25,50. 
The 'itemsTo' contains only one number (it is used for pagination) and it is 10 or 25 or 50. 
Depends on the numer it have i want to add bootstrap style 'selected' to my <select>

Comment: The tag helper will set the option with `selected` attribute automatically if you set the `Model.ItemsTo` with either of these 10, 25, 50 values. You don't need to manually set the attribute.